# How to use tcl apis in a c code

Tags: tcl

I want to use some of the functionalities(APIs) of my tcl code in another "c" code file. But i am not getting how to do that especiallly how to link them. For that i have taken a very simple tcl code which contains one API which adds two numbers and prints the sum. Can anybody tell me how can i call this tcl code to get the sum. How can i write a c wrapper that will call this tcl code. Below is my sample tcl program that i am using :

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh8.5
proc add_two_nos { } {

set a 10

  set b 20

  set c [expr { $a + $b } ]

  puts " c is $c ......."

}
```

Comment: sorry for that. I have accepted now the few replys which were very helpful to me.

Comment: can anybody please reply on this. It is very urgent for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To evaluate a script from C code, use [`Tcl_Eval()`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclLib/Eval.htm) or one of its close relatives. In order to use that API, you need to link in the Tcl library, [initialize the Tcl library](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclLib/FindExec.htm) and [create an interpreter](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclLib/CrtInterp.htm) to hold the execution context. Plus you really ought to do some work to retrieve the result and print it out (printing script errors out is particularly important, as that helps a *lot* with debugging!)

Thus, you get something like this:

```c
#include <tcl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Tcl_Interp *interp;
    int code;
    char *result;

    Tcl_FindExecutable(argv[0]);
    interp = Tcl_CreateInterp();
    code = Tcl_Eval(interp, "source myscript.tcl; add_two_nos");

    /* Retrieve the result... */
    result = Tcl_GetString(Tcl_GetObjResult(interp));

    /* Check for error! If an error, message is result. */
    if (code == TCL_ERROR) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR in script: %s\n", result);
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Print (normal) result if non-empty; we'll skip handling encodings for now */
    if (strlen(result)) {
        printf("%s\n", result);
    }

    /* Clean up */
    Tcl_DeleteInterp(interp);
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your reply. I will try this quickly and reply you back. Thanks once again

Comment: i am getting below errors while trying this :  simple_addition_wrapper_new.c:(.text+0x12): undefined reference to `Tcl_FindExecutable'
simple_addition_wrapper_new.c:(.text+0x17): undefined reference to `Tcl_CreateInterp'
simple_addition_wrapper_new.c:(.text+0x2f): undefined reference to `Tcl_Eval'
simple_addition_wrapper_new.c:(.text+0x3f): undefined reference to `Tcl_GetObjResult'
simple_addition_wrapper_new.c:(.text+0x47): undefined reference to `Tcl_GetString'
simple_addition_wrapper_new.c:(.text+0x9f): undefined reference to `Tcl_DeleteInterp'

Comment: please reply on this. I am not able to solve this problem yet.I have tried using different versions of tcl but still the above errors are there.

Comment: please do reply to these i am still struggling with this issue

Comment: probably tcl.h is not on your include path.

Comment: No that is not the case. tcl.h is included in the path but a conditional compilation is there in file tclDecls.h, under which all these definitions are there. Here is the snapshot of that particular portion of the tclDeclsh.h file :                     #if defined(USE_TCL_STUBS) && !defined(USE_TCL_STUB_PROCS)

/*
 * Inline function declarations:
 */

#ifndef Tcl_PkgProvideEx
#define Tcl_PkgProvideEx \
        (tclStubsPtr->tcl_PkgProvideEx) /* 0 */
#endif
#ifndef Tcl_PkgRequireEx
#define Tcl_PkgRequireEx \
.........    So all these declarations depends on above condition to become true.

Comment: If i comment this macro then these errors are not there, but other errors are there like : simple_addition_wrapper_new.c:(.text+0x17): undefined reference to `tclStubsPtr'
simple_addition_wrapper_new.c:(.text+0x2c): undefined reference to `tclStubsPtr'
simple_addition_wrapper_new.c:(.text+0x3d): undefined reference to `tclStubsPtr'
simple_addition_wrapper_new.c:(.text+0x5d): undefined reference to `tclStubsPtr'
simple_addition_wrapper_new.c:(.text+0x68): undefined reference to `tclStubsPtr'. There is also some condition where tclStubsPtr is defined. I have tried commenting that but no solutn.

Comment: The part of code of tclDecls.h under which tclStubsPtr is defined is here :   #ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
extern TclStubs *tclStubsPtr;
#ifdef __cplusplus
}                            I think i am missing something very basic. Can anybody please help me to solve this problem. It seems bit difficult for me to solve myself. Any help is definitely appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

I think i have sloved it out. You were correct. The problem was with the include method that i was using. I have the files tcl.h, tclDecls.h and tclPlatDecls.h included in the c code but these files were not existing in the path /usr/include so i was copying these files to that directory, may be it was not a proper way to do. Finally i have not copied those files to /usr/include and gave the include path while compiling. I have created executable and it is givingthe proper result on terminal. Thanks for your help.

Here is the exact c code i am using  :

```
#include <tcl.h>
#include <tclDecls.h>
#include <tclPlatDecls.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main (int argc, char **argv) {
Tcl_Interp *interp;
int code;
char *result;

printf("inside main function \n");
//    Tcl_InitStubs(interp, "8.5", 0);
Tcl_FindExecutable(argv[0]);
interp = Tcl_CreateInterp();
code = Tcl_Eval(interp, "source simple_addition.tcl; add_two_nos");

/* Retrieve the result... */
result = Tcl_GetString(Tcl_GetObjResult(interp));

/* Check for error! If an error, message is result. */
if (code == TCL_ERROR) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR in script: %s\n", result);
    exit(1);
}

/* Print (normal) result if non-empty; we'll skip handling encodings for now */
if (strlen(result)) {
    printf("%s\n", result);
}

/* Clean up */
Tcl_DeleteInterp(interp);
exit(0);
```

}

And to compile this code and to generate executable file i am using below command :

```
gcc simple_addition_wrapper_new.c -I/usr/include/tcl8.5/ -ltcl8.5 -o simple_addition_op
```

I have executed the file simple_addition_op and got below result which was proper

```
inside main function 
c is 30 .......
```

My special thanks to Donal Fellows and Johannes

Comment: In the main code i want the result to be 30. But now it is coming as an array of character. Can we use Tcl_GetInt? If yes, how to use it to get complete integer as return value ( 30 here)