# ERROR in script: can't find package Tk 8.4 (c wrapped tcl)

Tags: c, tcl, tk-toolkit

I've encountered the above mentioned error while I was trying to run a Tcl script embedded in C code:

```
Tcl_FindExecutable(argv[0]);
interp = Tcl_CreateInterp();
code = Tcl_Eval(interp, "source mainTCL.tcl");

/* Retrieve the result... */
result = Tcl_GetString(Tcl_GetObjResult(interp));

/* Check for error! If an error, message is result. */
if (code == TCL_ERROR) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR in script: %s\n", result);
    exit(1);
}
```

As suggested here: [how-to-use-tcl-apis-in-a-c-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13853770/how-to-use-tcl-apis-in-a-c-code).

When running this script from tclsh there is no error. I also tried setting `$auto_path` but it is not working.
I traced where error is happening by adding `puts` and it is here:

```
source "/usr/share/tcltk/tkcon2.7/tkcon.tcl"
```

What is the problem? Any help is appreciated... What is the difference between tclsh and C instance of Tcl interpreter?

Comment: Any reason for using 8.4? The current long-term support option is 8.5 and the current release recommended for new code is 8.6. 8.4 has been out of support for a few years now.

Comment: @DonalFellows : thanks for your comment; actually there is not any need to use 8.4 version, I have already installed 8.5 and 8.6 packages and all of these 3 packages work with tclsh but the problem with C wrapping persists.

Comment: What does happend if you replace `code = Tcl_Eval(interp, "source mainTCL.tcl");` by `code = Tcl_Eval(interp, "/usr/share/tcltk/tkcon2.7/tkcon.tcl");`? Can you locate the error in `tkcon.tcl` file?

Comment: @purplepsycho : It shows same error and I realized that the error is located at below command in tkcon.tcl file: "package require Tk 8.4" ; I tried to replace the command to use TK 8.5 or TK 8.6 packages but the problem isn't resolved.