# how to link to the tclOO functions in the Tcl C API

Tags: c, tcl, linker-errors

As a short example of what I can't do:

```
#include <tcl.h>
#include <tclOO.h>

int main(void) {
    Tcl_Interp *interp = Tcl_CreateInterp();
    Tcl_Obj *obj = Tcl_NewStringObj("myObject", -1);
    Tcl_Object object = Tcl_GetObjectFromObj(interp, obj);
    return 0;
}
```

Then compiling with:

```
gcc main.c -o tclOOTest -ltcl
```

I of course get an error from the linker because I'm not linking against a library that has a definition for Tcl_GetObjectFromObj. Trouble is I don't know what library to link against. I thought tclOO was built into tcl since 8.6 (which is what I'm using).

Here is the error:

```
/tmp/ccZnpdY8.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x33): undefined reference to `Tcl_GetObjectFromObj'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Can you shows us the exact link error?

Comment: Sure. Just edited the post to include the error.

Comment: Simple google search show me this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13927689/1480131 since it isn't tcl8.5 but 8.6, I'd suggest `-ltcl8.6`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that does not work. On my machine, libtcl.so is just a link to libtcl8.6.so. I tried anyway, but it gives the same linker error.

Comment: What is the path of `libtcl.so` in your machine?

Comment: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtcl.so

Comment: @Pablo, just to clarify, the problem is not with linking against the Tcl library. The problem is that the functions that I want to use -- those that are related to tclOO -- are not IN the libtcl.so. And I don't know what library I'm supposed to link against. There is not, for example, a libtclOO.so that gets installed with Tcl. I can't tack on do -ltclOO. Thanks

Comment: Ok, I don't know tcl, but I found this [page](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclLib/OOInitStubs.htm): *If you are linking against the Tcl 8.5 forward compatibility package for TclOO, only the stub-enabled configuration is supported and **you should also link against the TclOO independent stub library**; that library is an integrated part of the main Tcl stub library in Tcl 8.6.* ...

Comment: Looking at that I've tried to find the name of the stub library, I found [this](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/tcl8.6-dev/filelist): Debian installs the file `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtclstub8.6.a`, so the lib name is presumably `-ltclstub.8.6`. Look in your lib directory (or package manager) for a `libtclstub8.6.a`/`libtclstub8.6.so` file.

Comment: Can you compile it with `gcc main.c -o tclOOTest $(pkg-config tcl --libs)`?

Comment: "pkg-config tcl --libs" doesn't return anything on my system. I don't really understand the page you linked to. It says "When using this function, either the C #define symbol USE_TCLOO_STUBS should be defined and your library code linked against the Tcl stub library, or that #define symbol should not be defined and your library code linked against the Tcl main library directly." I'm llinking against the main library and not defining the symbol. If I include a call to Tcl_OOInitStubs in the program above, it does not solve the problem.

Comment: I don't think I can help you more. The truth is I have no clue about tcl, but I know how libraries in general are written, installed, linked against, etc. The page I found is the official documentation. If pkg-config did not return anything, then I don't know you installed tcl. Which distro are you using?

Comment: Thanks for trying, Pablo! I've tried this on ubuntu and on arch. It was on ubuntu that pkg-config didn't find anything. on arch there's a tcl.pc file. on ubuntu there is none. but I'm sure tcl is installed on both systems because I can call the regular API functions, just not the tclOO ones. Anyway, I appreciate your time!

Comment: perhaps the tcl folks have a forum of their own or a mailing list, you could ask there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TclOO API, unlike much of the rest of Tcl, only exports itself via a stubs table. You should `#define` the symbol `USE_TCL_STUBS` to be 1 before you `#include` the Tcl header file, and link against the `tclstub` library. (This is the recommended way of building extensions anyway.)

[EDIT]: If you're embedding Tcl within your program, you need a [more complex procedure](http://wiki.tcl.tk/2074#pagetoc37f37e65). Basically, you need to partition your program into the parts that are an application and the parts that are an *internal* extension. The parts that call `Tcl_CreateInterp` are most likely the application part, and the parts that access the TclOO API are the extension (and will need to call `Tcl_InitStubs` and `Tcl_OOInitStubs` in an initialisation function).

The extension parts need to be compiled with `USE_TCL_STUBS` defined. (As it is critical, you might put that as a `#define` at the top of the file. The wiki page mentions `USE_TCLOO_STUBS` as well, but that's implied by `USE_TCL_STUBS`.) The extension parts need to be built without it. You can call the initialisation function that installs your internal extension immediately after the `Tcl_CreateInterp` call, before you start running any (non-built-in) scripts. Then when you link everything you link *both* against `libtclstub` and `libtcl`.

The reason for this complexity is that TclOO started out as a separate extension itself, and that never supported external API references. I probably ought to relax those restrictions for Tcl 8.7…

Comment: A celebrity answer (in this context)! Thanks! This answer does solve the issue, as linking against tclstub clears the linker error. But now the example program above seg faults at the first call into the Tcl API (the call to Tcl_CreateInterp). I'm guessing the problem is I don't understand the stub library or how to use it.

Comment: That edit and the included link were extremely helpful. Thank you!